# output expanded ip list from text in python

Tags: python, regex

I have text that contains IP and subnet data.  I need to output each IP within a given range.  The input looks like this:

```
10.14.21.23 0.0.0.0  
20.54.0.0 0.0.127.255  
30.76.21.0 0.0.0.255  
40.24.21.135 0.0.0.0
```

and the output needs to look like this:

```
10.14.21.23  
20.54.0.1  
20.54.0.2  
20.54.0.3  
20.54.0.4  
...   
20.54.127.254  
30.76.21.1  
30.76.21.2  
30.76.21.3  
30.76.21.4  
...   
30.76.21.254   
40.24.21.135
```

I have isolated the IPs with:

```
for line in file.readlines():
    if re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+?', line):
        tuples = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', line)
```

This places the IP and subnet into tuples[0] and tuples[1].  Is this the best way to handle this data?  How do you calculate each IP within a given range?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you calculate each IP within a given range

Comment: I cant find any range in it :(. If you give like `20.54.0.0 20.54.128.255` then it might be correct range.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipcalc might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ipcalc:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ipcalc
import sys

for data in sys.argv[1:]:
  with open(data) as data:
    for data in data:
      data = data.split()
      # Convert subnet mask to count
      data[1] = ipcalc.IP(data[1]).bin().count('0')
      data = ipcalc.Network(*data)
      data = list(data)
      if len(data) == 1:
        print data[0]
      else:
        for data in data[1:-1]:
          print data
```

Ref:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipcalc
- http://ipcalc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/